# Type of input fields in "form" doesnt work with Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, input

I have a problem with my project. I have a timetable with a row, in which is possible to add more rows dynamically with Jquery.

The codes are:

```
<?php

session_start();

?>

<html lang="es">
    <head>
    <meta charset="iso-8859-1">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="rows_management.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="elements">
    <form id="data" action="timetable_processing.php" method="post">
    <table border="1" id="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
    <td>Hour</td>
    <td>Monday</td>
    <td>Tuesday</td>
    <td>Wednesday</td>
    <td>Thursday</td>
    <td>Friday</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <tr class="first-row">
    <td><input type="time" name="hour[0]" placeholder="hour"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject_mon[0]" placeholder="Subject"><br><input type="text" name="id_user_mon[0]"placeholder="Id_teacher"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="subject_tue[0]" placeholder="Subject"><br><input type="text" name="id_user_tue[0]"placeholder="Id_teacher"></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="subject_wed[0]" placeholder="Subject"><br><input type="text" name="id_user_wed[0]"placeholder="Id_teacher"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject_thu[0]" placeholder="Subject"><br><input type="text" name="id_user_thu[0]"placeholder="Id_teacher"></td>
<td><input type="text" name="subject_fri[0]" placeholder="Subject"><br><input type="text" name="id_user_fri[0]"placeholder="Id_teacher"></td>
    <td class="remove">Remove</td>
    </tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="year" id="year" value="<?php echo $year ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="class" id="class" value="<?php echo $class ?>">

    </tbody>
    </table>

    <input type="button" id="add" value="Add row" />
    <input type="submit" id="submit"  value="Submit">

    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        $connection = mysql_connect("localhost", "alonsosjumper", "alonsosjumper") or die('It´s not possible to connect: ' . mysql_error());
echo '<br>OK, all correct<br>';

mysql_select_db("project", $connection) or die('It´s not possible to open the database');

    $query= "select id_user, name, surnames from users where user_type='teacher' order by id_user";
    $result= mysql_query($query);

    echo ' <p>Teachers:</p>
    <table border="1" width="auto">
    <tr><td>Id_user</td><td>Name</td><td>Surnames</td></tr>';

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

    echo "<tr><td>".$fila['id_user']."</td><td>".$fila['name']."</td><td>".$fila['surnames']."</td></tr>";
}

    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

and:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var countInputs = ($(".first-row").length);

    $("#add").on('click', function(){
        $('#table > tbody:last').after("<tr><td><input type='time' name='hour['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Hour'></td><td><input type='text' name='subject_mon['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Subject'><br><input type='text' name='id_user_mon['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Teacher'></td><td><input type='text' name='subject_tue['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Subject'><br><input type='text' name='id_user_tue['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Teacher'></td><td><input type='text' name='subject_wed['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Subject'><br><input type='text' name='id_user_wed['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Teacher'></td><td><input type='text' name='subject_thu['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Subject'><br><input type='text' name='id_user_thu['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Teacher'></td><td><input type='text' name='subject_fri['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Subject'><br><input type='text' name='id_user_fri['+countInputs+']' placeholder='Teacher'></td><td class='remove'>Remover</td></tr>");
        countInputs++;

    });

    $(document).on("click",".remove",function(){
        if (countInputs>1)
        {
        var parent = $(this).parents().get(0);
        $(parent).remove();
        countInputs--;

        }
        else
            alert("It´s not possible to remove the last row");
    });

});
```

My doubt is:

The first row created works perfectly in hour with the input="date":

```
<td><input type="time" name="hour[0]" placeholder="hour"></td>
```

However, in the Jquery code:

```
<td><input type="time" name="hour[0]" placeholder="hour"></td>
```

it doesn´t work. It doesn´t accept the type time. I´ve tried with another types, like password or date and neither. I think Jquery doesn´t recognize the form.

Can anybody give me a solution please?

Thank you!

Comment: It's more likely that the browser isn't recognizing it. jQuery just passes it along to `.innerHTML` Note, your string concatenation isn't working, you're quotes are wrong (which is likely the real cause of your problem)

Comment: *"My doubt is"* The word you want there is "question," not "doubt." You've probably seen "doubt" a lot on SO, because it's (apparently) dialect on the Indian subcontinent. But from your name and the language of your HTML page, I'm guessing you're not on the Indian subcontinent. :-) I only mention this because even though it's not your first language, your English is excellent.

Comment: @KevinB In Internet Explorer the first row doesn´t work neither, however, on Chrome, the first row works but the other no. I changed name='hour['+countInputs+']' by name='hour["+countInputs+"]' and it doesn´t work...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder No, i´m from Spain xD. I thought doubt could be used as "question" xD Thanks for the correction :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your string conctination is a bit off, parts like `name='hour['+countInputs+']'` should be `name='hour["+countInputs+"]'` since you're using  `"` to quote your string.

Comment: Sorry, your answer doesn´t work. In Internet Explorer the first row doesn´t work neither, however, on Chrome, the first row works but the other no.

Comment: Now it works!, it was a countInputs that it was with the simple '. Thankss